# Pygame : Snake game How to make making snake go throught walls or creating a fram around the edge?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying lately to make a drawing wall as well or making the snake of this game to go through the wall but i don't know how to program it. If anybody have a clue how to make the snake go through the wall or drawing a frame on the edge could you please help me how to program it ? and if there is any recommendation to add this game could you please add it here. These are the codes :

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

Snakespeed= 17
Window_Width= 800
Window_Height= 500
Cell_Size = 20 #Width and height of the cells
assert Window_Width % Cell_Size == 0, "Window width must be a multiple of cell size."     #Ensuring that the cells fit perfectly in the window. eg if cell size was 10     and window width or windowheight were 15 only 1.5 cells would fit.
assert Window_Height % Cell_Size == 0, "Window height must be a multiple of cell size."  #Ensuring that only whole integer number of cells fit perfectly in the window.
Cell_W= int(Window_Width / Cell_Size) #Cell Width 
Cell_H= int(Window_Height / Cell_Size) #Cellc Height


White= (255,255,255)
Black= (0,0,0)
Red= (255,0,0) #Defining element colors for the program.
Green= (0,255,0)
DARKGreen= (0,155,0)
DARKGRAY= (40,40,40)
YELLOW= (255,255,0)
Red_DARK= (150,0,0)
BLUE= (0,0,255)
BLUE_DARK= (0,0,150)



BGCOLOR = Black # Background color


UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'      # Defining keyboard keys.  
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

HEAD = 0 # Syntactic sugar: index of the snake's head

def main():
    global SnakespeedCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT

    pygame.init()
    SnakespeedCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((Window_Width, Window_Height))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')

    showStartScreen()
    while True:
        runGame()
        showGameOverScreen()


def runGame():
    # Set a random start point.
    startx = random.randint(5, Cell_W - 6)
    starty = random.randint(5, Cell_H - 6)
    wormCoords = [{'x': startx,     'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 1, 'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 2, 'y': starty}]
    direction = RIGHT

    # Start the apple in a random place.
    apple = getRandomLocation()

    while True: # main game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT ) and direction != RIGHT:
                    direction = LEFT
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT ) and direction != LEFT:
                    direction = RIGHT
                elif (event.key == K_UP ) and direction != DOWN:
                    direction = UP
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN ) and direction != UP:
                    direction = DOWN
                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()

        # check if the Snake has hit itself or the edge
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == -1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == Cell_W or     wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == -1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == Cell_H:
            return # game over 
        for wormBody in wormCoords[1:]:
            if wormBody['x'] == wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] and wormBody['y'] == wormCoords[HEAD]    ['y']: 
                return # game over

        # check if Snake has eaten an apply
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple['y']:
            # don't remove worm's tail segment
            apple = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple somewhere
        else:
            del wormCoords[-1] # remove worm's tail segment

        # move the worm by adding a segment in the direction it is moving
        if direction == UP:
            newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] - 1}
        elif direction == DOWN:
            newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] + 1}
        elif direction == LEFT:
            newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
        elif direction == RIGHT:
            newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] + 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
        wormCoords.insert(0, newHead)
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawGrid()
        drawWorm(wormCoords)
        drawApple(apple)
        drawScore(len(wormCoords) - 3)
        pygame.display.update()
        SnakespeedCLOCK.tick(Snakespeed)

def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, White)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (Window_Width - 200, Window_Height - 30)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)


def checkForKeyPress():
    if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
        terminate()
    keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
    if len(keyUpEvents) == 0:
        return None
    if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_ESCAPE:
        terminate()
    return keyUpEvents[0].key


def showStartScreen():
    titleFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
    titleSurf1 = titleFont.render('Snake!', True, White, DARKGreen)
    degrees1 = 0
    degrees2 = 0
    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        rotatedSurf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf1, degrees1)
        rotatedRect1 = rotatedSurf1.get_rect()
        rotatedRect1.center = (Window_Width / 2, Window_Height / 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf1, rotatedRect1)

        drawPressKeyMsg()

        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
            return
        pygame.display.update()
        SnakespeedCLOCK.tick(Snakespeed)
        degrees1 += 3 # rotate by 3 degrees each frame
        degrees2 += 7 # rotate by 7 degrees each frame


def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def getRandomLocation():
    return {'x': random.randint(0, Cell_W - 1), 'y': random.randint(0, Cell_H - 1)}


def showGameOverScreen():
    gameOverFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
    gameSurf = gameOverFont.render('Game', True, White)
    overSurf = gameOverFont.render('Over', True, White)
    gameRect = gameSurf.get_rect()
    overRect = overSurf.get_rect()
    gameRect.midtop = (Window_Width / 2, 10)
    overRect.midtop = (Window_Width / 2, gameRect.height + 10 + 25)

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(gameSurf, gameRect)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(overSurf, overRect)
    drawPressKeyMsg()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(500)
    checkForKeyPress() # clear out any key presses in the event queue

    while True:
        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
            return

def drawScore(score):
    scoreSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score: %s' % (score), True, White)
    scoreRect = scoreSurf.get_rect()
    scoreRect.topleft = (Window_Width - 120, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(scoreSurf, scoreRect)


def drawWorm(wormCoords):
    for coord in wormCoords:
        x = coord['x'] * Cell_Size
        y = coord['y'] * Cell_Size
        wormSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, Cell_Size, Cell_Size)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGreen, wormSegmentRect)
        wormInnerSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x + 4, y + 4, Cell_Size - 8, Cell_Size - 8)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, Green, wormInnerSegmentRect)


def drawApple(coord):
    x = coord['x'] * Cell_Size
    y = coord['y'] * Cell_Size
    appleRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, Cell_Size, Cell_Size)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, Red, appleRect)


def drawGrid():
    for x in range(0, Window_Width, Cell_Size): # draw vertical lines
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x, 0), (x, Window_Height))
    for y in range(0, Window_Height, Cell_Size): # draw horizontal lines
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (0, y), (Window_Width, y))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except SystemExit:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you how it can be done but giving it the perfection should be yours....
like making the wall fit the boundry cells and making the snake die as it hits the wall not the end of the window.

First create these two functions.

```
def createWall():
    global boundry
    boundry=[]
    for i in range(0,Window_Width):
        boundry.append((i,0))
        boundry.append((i,Window_Height-18))
    for i in range(0,Window_Height):
        boundry.append((0,i))
        boundry.append((Window_Width-18,i))

def drawWall():
    for each in boundry:
        wallRect = pygame.Rect(each[0],each[1], Cell_Size-2, Cell_Size-2)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGreen, wallRect)
```

now Call `createWall()` in `main()` inside of while loop just before calling `runGame()`
and Call `drawWall()` in `runGame()` in the end just before calling `pygame.display.update()`.

**EDITS:**

To make your snake pass through the wall you need to manipulate his `head` accordingly
replace you `runGame()` function with this piece of code:

```
def runGame():
    # Set a random start point.
    startx = random.randint(5, Cell_W - 6)
    starty = random.randint(5, Cell_H - 6)
    wormCoords = [{'x': startx,     'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 1, 'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 2, 'y': starty}]
    direction = RIGHT

    # Start the apple in a random place.
    apple = getRandomLocation()

    while True: # main game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT ) and direction != RIGHT:
                    direction = LEFT
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT ) and direction != LEFT:
                    direction = RIGHT
                elif (event.key == K_UP ) and direction != DOWN:
                    direction = UP
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN ) and direction != UP:
                    direction = DOWN
                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()

        # check if the Snake has hit itself
        for wormBody in wormCoords[1:]:
            if wormBody['x'] == wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] and wormBody['y'] == wormCoords[HEAD]    ['y']: 
                return # game over

        # check if Snake has eaten an apple
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple['y']:
            # don't remove worm's tail segment
            apple = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple somewhere
        else:
            del wormCoords[-1] # remove worm's tail segment

        # move the worm by adding a segment in the direction it is moving
        if direction == UP:
            if wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == -1: #if upper wall then move the head to emerge from lower wall
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': Cell_H-1}
            else:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] - 1}

        elif direction == DOWN:  
            if wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == Cell_H: #if lower wall then move the head to emerge from upper wall
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': 0}
            else:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] + 1}

        elif direction == LEFT:
            if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == -1: #if left wall then move the head to emerge from right wall
                newHead = {'x': Cell_W-1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            else:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}

        elif direction == RIGHT:
            if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == Cell_W: #if right wall then move the head to emerge from left wall
                newHead = {'x': 0, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            else:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] + 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
        wormCoords.insert(0, newHead)

        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawGrid()
        drawWorm(wormCoords)
        drawApple(apple)
        drawScore(len(wormCoords) - 3)
        pygame.display.update()
        SnakespeedCLOCK.tick(Snakespeed)
```

Comment: It works but sometimes the apple randomly appear in the wall. How i can make the snake go through the wall and go back from the other side ?

Comment: First of all you need to kno what you are making....I you want the snake to come from the other side then there is no reason to include wall....

Comment: Anyway if I get you clearly then you need a wall...completely covering the arena boundary (know gap) and still you want your snake to pass the boundary and come from other side?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !! IT WORKS ! Do you have any other recommendation how to improve this game ?

Comment: I don't think so there might be optimizations but they are unnecessary... and code is neatly written